# Pagination links always should be ten what ever which link is active,

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Here my code is

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination"> ';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul><!--pagination-->';
    $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next &rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li ><a class="mj_blackbtn" href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Here links

[enter link description here](http://kbmrecruitment.com/Jobs/JobsList/Active/6)

Tell me particular css to show only 10 links and hide all except ten , what ever which link is active should show always only 10 links ever, I tried $Confiig['num_links'], but it distrb css, it keep 10 before and 10 after active

Answer (score 1):

try this You can define current page on `Codeigniter` with and manage pages in controller.

```
$config["cur_page"] = $your_last_page_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot show 10 link, because if you are at page 5, then what should it show?

`1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9 10` ha?

The problem is CI always shows the links before and the links after equally, I think you should set
`$config['num_links'] = 4;`

to show 9 links instead of 10.